# WPF:The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: wpf, async-await

i'm learning c# and wpf.
i tried to load a img from net and bind it to a Image,but failed.

it says "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it"

but i already used "Img1.Dispatcher.Invoke()",why it casue this exception again?

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Img1.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
    {
         Img1.Source = await DownloadImg("http address");
    });
}

private Task<ImageSource> DownloadImg(string url)
{
     return Task.Run(() =>
     {
         ImageSource source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(url));
         return source;
     });
}
```

Comment: From the answer to the duplicate question, you may replace BitmapFrame by BitmapImage. The important thing is to first asynchronously download the image buffer, and then create and return a frozen BitmapSource.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the Image because you have to do this in the UI thread. You can make a private field and in your constructor you set this with `_dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. In your `Task` you have to use this dispatcher and call the method `Invoke` to set your Image. 
More info: [Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)